# Different layouts in Pre-kitkat and Post-kitkat version in android layouts

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, user-interface

Lollipop Image :
[Screenshot from Lollipop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzbs4.png)

Pre Kitkat :
[Screenshot from pre Kitkat versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkVQh.png)

XML file code :

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/backgrounda">


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/home_round" />


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.16" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.22"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="@color/appcolortemp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.28" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.22"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="@color/appcolortemp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.11" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.51" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.22"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="@color/appcolortemp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.11" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.63" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.22"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="@color/appcolortemp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.51" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.22"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.11" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="@color/appcolortemp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.28" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.22"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.11" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="@color/appcolortemp" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.39"></LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.22"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.2"
            android:background="@color/appcolortemp"></LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Problem :

There is some UI problem in Pre-Kitkat version.
In Pre-Kitkat versions there is a white strip in the middle of the screen
and for Kitkat and above version it is working fine.

What is a problem with this code? I cant even figure out the main cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reviewed my code and I found the problem.
Problem was in my code I had another layout similar to this layout and by mistake I have added webview in my layout so that was causing problem.
:)